# C# - Wait For All Tasks In Array To Complete Or Fail

Tags: c#, task, cancellation

I have a list of Tasks, the tasks do work on different databases then update a set of results on a central database.

If I can't connect to the central database the desired behaviour is to cancel all the tasks, wait for the running tasks to successfully stop (as it's a cooperative thing) then quit the program.

I've written a few lines of code to test cancelling tasks:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var taskList = new List<Task>();
taskList.Add(new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); }, cancellationTokenSource.Token));
taskList.Add(new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); }, cancellationTokenSource.Token));
taskList.ForEach(task => task.Start());
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

I know I should normally periodically check the cancellation token within the tasks executing code but for now I'm just testing my understanding of how cancelling works.

When I run it I get the error:

[image]

You can pass a cancellation token to WaitAll but thats for actually cancelling the WaitAll

[image]

Essentially I just want to wait until all tasks have either run to completion or stopped due to being cancelled so I can safely quit.

I feel like I'm probably missing something simple, if anyone could shed some light on how to accomplish this that would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of [Task.WaitAll throws OperationCanceledException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595720/task-waitall-throws-operationcanceledexception)

Essentially what you need is

```
Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC).Wait()
```

As mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks! You're right it is a duplication of above, sorry!

Comment: This will throw aggregate exception as the first OP's snippet.

Comment: Thanks for marking it correct. At least I can write comments and avoid posting them in answers going forward :).

Answer (score 2):

The `TaskCanceledException` is an exception that is always thrown when you cancel a running Task. You simply need to handle it with a try-catch block. This goes against Microsoft's own philosophy of trying to avoid throwing exceptions when possible [(Best Practices For Exceptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions).

The easiest solution would look something like this:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var taskList = new List<Task>
{
    Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1); }),
    Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); }, cancellationTokenSource.Token),
    Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); }, cancellationTokenSource.Token)
};

cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

try
{
    Task.WhenAll(taskList).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tasks were cancelled");;
}

Console.WriteLine(taskList[0].Status);
Console.WriteLine(taskList[1].Status);
Console.WriteLine(taskList[2].Status);
```

Comment: Nice twist with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`; OP just needs to be aware that this only returns the first observed exception, whereas `Wait` returns an `AggregateException` with all of them.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is very true! I prefer `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` over `Wait()` because you don't have to unpack the inner exception and delivers generally a more relevant StackTrace.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, avoid mixing blocking code (`Task.WaitAll`, `Wait`, ...) with nonblocking code; `Task.WhenAll` may be the the better choice. As is hinted at in the post in Amogh's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832040/195651), you likely want to use this instead:

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray())
          .ContinueWith(t => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

For example, the following code will print `Canceled`, `RanToCompletion` and `Faulted`:

```cs
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var taskList = new List<Task>
{
    new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); }, cancellationTokenSource.Token),
    new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); }),
    new Task(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    })
};

taskList.ForEach(task => task.Start());
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray())
          .ContinueWith(t => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);

Console.WriteLine(taskList[0].Status);
Console.WriteLine(taskList[1].Status);
Console.WriteLine(taskList[2].Status);
```

That said, this only makes sense when you intend to observe the individual tasks afterwards. If you don't, embrace the exception(s) instead.