# Waiting for multiple tasks when some might be cancelled

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation

I'm trying to wait for multiple tasks, and I expect that some might be cancelled. I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595720/task-waitall-throws-operationcanceledexception) question as a source of inspiration to have `WhenAll` handle cancelled tasks accordingly...

However, if none of the tasks ever get cancelled, this in turn throws an exception too!

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();

var task1 = Task.Delay(100, source.Token);
source.Cancel();
var task2 = Task.Delay(300);

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ContinueWith(_ => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

In the example above if the `source.Cancel()` is NOT executed, then the final `await` will throw an exception. I could fix that by removing the `ContinueWith` from the final line, but then if a task IS cancelled, the `WhenAll` will fail with the same error.

What's the correct course of action to wait for a list of tasks when some of them might (but don't have to) be cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `TaskContinuationOption` you pass. In your example you use `OnlyOnCanceled`. So it only continues with that if a task was cancelled.

I'm not sure what the desired behaviour is when a task was cancelled. If you only want to proceed when none of them was cancelled, you could use `NotOnCanceled`. If you want to proceed in either case, with cancelled tasks or not, then you could for example use `NotOnFaulted`, since cancellation is not regarded as fault.

Comment: I was basing my code on the question / answer provided from the link, but you're right! It should be `NotOnFaulted`, rather than `NotOnCanceled`. Thanks!

Comment: aah, I wasn't sure if the behaviour should be the same, e.g. just proceed when all are completed or cancelled :)

Answer (score 2):

The `ContinueWith` is a [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) method, generally unsuitable for application code. Mixing it with `await` is even more inadvisable, since then you use two different mechanisms having slightly different semantics to accomplish the same goal. Your example implies that you want to ignore exceptions caused by the cancellation of the `CancellationTokenSource`. My advice is to just `catch` these exceptions and ignore them.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(100);

var task1 = Task.Delay(200, cts.Token);
var task2 = Task.Delay(300);

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException) {  } // Ignore cancellation exceptions
```

You can be even more specific by using the [`when`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when) contextual keyword, in order to avoid ignoring exceptions originated by unknown `CancellationTokenSource`s:

```
catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == cts.Token) { }
```

This may create different problems though, because a method may wrap the supplied `CancellationToken` into a [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource) `CancellationTokenSource`, in which case the `catch`/`when` may not handle an `OperationCanceledException` that was originated by a known token.

Comment: Not sure if I'll actually use your recommendation, but the answer itself is very informative. Thank you!

Comment: On a side note - if `ContinueWith` is ill-advised... then what would be an alternative if you need to dynamically add "do action X after task Y" type of logic into your code? Keyword here being "dynamically"...

Comment: @Shaamaan *"do action X after task Y"* can be implemented as `await Y; X();`. If you want to do the action X conditionally, then put this code in an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) method, and call this method conditionally. Making it `async void` will ensure that any unhandled exceptions inside this method will be surfaced (normally by crashing the process).